# mapbox gl js, connect points with line

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a source with a geojson with a bunch of Features of type Point.

Is it possible to draw a line through them? I've tried Layout with type line, but it produces points...

I don't want to create an additional source with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to draw a line through them?

No. For starters, Mapbox GL JS wouldn't know in which order to draw the line.

> I don't want to create an additional source with the same data.

That would be the correct solution: simply construct a new GeoJSON on the fly that uses the coordinates of each point as the coordinates of a line `LineString` feature. I'm not sure what your reservations are.